# How to avoid multiple joins on the same table (it has 200 columns to hold IDs. Another table has a mapping of IDs to values)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a table Checklist with the following columns

ChkId, Q1_ID, Comment1, Checked1, Q2_ID, Comment2, Checked2, ...
Q200_ID...

I have a table Questions with the following columns

Q_ID, Prompt

How do I replace Checklist.Q#_ID with the matching Questions.Prompt without joining them up to 200 times? Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: Your best bet is to probably pivot the Checklist table inside a CTE or possibly temp table and then join onto the CTE

Comment: Have a look at dynamic queries.

Comment: This is a horrible design. You should normalize your data model, then the query is a simple join.

Comment: `Rollback;Rollback;Rollback;`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts to have them deleted.

Comment: How can I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186237/normalize-a-mysql-table-with-more-than-250-boolean-columns/186251#186251) to understand why your original design is a very bad idea from a relational database point of view.

Basically, you have "squashed" two entities into one! Your scenario is **very** similar to that question! You need to normalise your data - this will greatly assist your query formulation and speed!

It appears that there are two entities here (IMHO) a checklist entity and a question entity.

Checklists are identified by a checklist_id (chk_id) and questions are uniquely identifed by a checklist_id **and** a question_id. Perhaps "quiz" might be a better name? You could have history quizzes, sports quizzes &c. with different chk_id's.

So, in order to tackle the underlying problem, you should create a question table (see SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11002/2/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE question
(
  chk_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  q_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  q_comment VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  q_checked BIT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT question_pk PRIMARY KEY (chk_id, q_id)
);
```

You could implement my strategy in `VIEW`s if you can't change the underlying table structure - that will be a bit clumsy, but still better than your current scenario!

Sample checklist table:

A sample of the first 3 questions extracted from your checklist table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE checklist -- you have this already!
(
  chk_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  q1_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  q1_comment VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, -- or whatever size suits.
  q1_checked BIT NOT NULL,

  q2_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  q2_comment VARCHAR (255),
  q2_checked BIT NOT NULL,

  q3_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  q3_comment VARCHAR (255),
  q3_checked BIT NOT NULL

  -- &c. 197 times.
);

INSERT INTO checklist
VALUES
(233, 1, 'Good question!', 1, 2, 'Crap', 0, 3, 'Better', 1),
(234, 1, 'An OK question', 0,  2, 'Bleuch...', 1,  3, 'Brilliant!!', 0);
```

If the "comment" field is the question itself - i.e. "prompt", substitute text of your choice - my comments are opinions about the question... not really sure. Easily modifiable!

You will then need to construct a series of 200 `INSERT`s like this:

```
INSERT INTO question
SELECT 
  chk_id, 
  q1_id, 
  q1_comment, 
  q1_checked 
FROM checklist;
```

You will have to do this 200 times (q2... q200). Obviously, this will require some work (either manual typing or scripting) to get your data out of your original entity, but it **will** be worth it in the long run!

Here are the three question entries (by two checklists - history or sport):

```
SELECT * FROM question;
```

Result:

```
chk_id  q_id          q_comment     q_checked
   233     1     Good question!          true
   233     2               Crap         false
   233     3             Better          true
   234     1     An OK question         false
   234     2          Bleuch...          true
   234     3        Brilliant!!         false
```

Your tables will be much more performant and much easier to manipulate!

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I've assumed that the `comment` field is what you're referring to as `prompt`.

Build some test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestingTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestingTable
CREATE TABLE #TestingTable 
(
ChkID int
,Q1_ID int
,Comment1 varchar(20)
,Q2_ID int
,Comment2 varchar(20)
,Q3_ID int
,Comment3 varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #TestingTable (ChkID, Q1_ID, Comment1, Q2_ID, Comment2, Q3_ID, Comment3)
VALUES
 (1,11,'Row1 Comment1', 12, 'Row1 Comment2', 13, 'Row1 Comment3')
,(2,21,'Row2 Comment1', 22, 'Row2 Comment2', 23, 'Row2 Comment3')
,(3,31,'Row3 Comment1', 32, 'Row3 Comment2', 33, 'Row3 Comment3')
,(4,41,'Row4 Comment1', 42, 'Row4 Comment2', 43, 'Row4 Comment3')
```

Which gives you this data set;

```
ChkID   Q1_ID   Comment1        Q2_ID   Comment2        Q3_ID   Comment3
1       11      Row1 Comment1   12      Row1 Comment2   13      Row1 Comment3
2       21      Row2 Comment1   22      Row2 Comment2   23      Row2 Comment3
3       31      Row3 Comment1   32      Row3 Comment2   33      Row3 Comment3
4       41      Row4 Comment1   42      Row4 Comment2   43      Row4 Comment3
```

Then we can do some trickery with UNPIVOT

```
SELECT u2.ChkID, u2.Q_ID, u2.Comment
FROM #TestingTable tt
UNPIVOT
(
  AnswerID
  for Q_ID in (Q1_ID, Q2_ID, Q3_ID)
) u1
UNPIVOT
(
  Comment
  for Comment_ID in (Comment1, Comment2, Comment3)
) u2
WHERE SUBSTRING(u2.Q_ID,2,1) = RIGHT(Comment_ID,1)
```

Which gives us this result;

```
ChkID   Q_ID    Comment
1       Q1_ID   Row1 Comment1
1       Q2_ID   Row1 Comment2
1       Q3_ID   Row1 Comment3
2       Q1_ID   Row2 Comment1
2       Q2_ID   Row2 Comment2
2       Q3_ID   Row2 Comment3
3       Q1_ID   Row3 Comment1
3       Q2_ID   Row3 Comment2
3       Q3_ID   Row3 Comment3
4       Q1_ID   Row4 Comment1
4       Q2_ID   Row4 Comment2
4       Q3_ID   Row4 Comment3
```

Which is what I *think* you're after. You'll have to do a little work on that `WHERE` clause to fit the use case of 200+ columns (this only works for columns with a single digit length) and you'll probably want to put a clause there on the ChkID too. This should get you on your way if I've understood your question correctly.

If you're not sure how many columns you're going to have, then you'll want to do some dynamic querying to pass through your column list. Something like this;

Test Data (a temp table won't work this time because we're using sys.columns)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestingTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE TestingTable; 
CREATE TABLE TestingTable 
(
ChkID int
,Q1_ID int
,Comment1 varchar(20)
,Q2_ID int
,Comment2 varchar(20)
,Q3_ID int
,Comment3 varchar(20)
,Q200_ID int
,Comment200 varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO TestingTable (ChkID, Q1_ID, Comment1, Q2_ID, Comment2, Q3_ID, Comment3, Q200_ID, Comment200)
VALUES
 (1,11,'Row1 Comment1', 12, 'Row1 Comment2', 13, 'Row1 Comment3', 1200, 'Row1 Comment200')
,(2,21,'Row2 Comment1', 22, 'Row2 Comment2', 23, 'Row2 Comment3', 2200, 'Row1 Comment200')
,(3,31,'Row3 Comment1', 32, 'Row3 Comment2', 33, 'Row3 Comment3', 3200, 'Row1 Comment200')
,(4,41,'Row4 Comment1', 42, 'Row4 Comment2', 43, 'Row4 Comment3', 4200, 'Row1 Comment200')
```

Dynamic version of the query above

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @QuestionList nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @CommentList nvarchar(max)

SELECT @QuestionList = COALESCE(@QuestionList+',' , '') + c.name
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TestingTable')
    AND c.name LIKE 'Q%' 
    AND c.name LIKE '%_ID'

SELECT @CommentList = COALESCE(@CommentList+',' , '') + c.name
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TestingTable')
    AND c.name LIKE 'Comment%' 

SET @sql = N'SELECT u2.ChkID, u2.Q_ID, u2.Comment
    FROM TestingTable tt
    UNPIVOT
    (
      AnswerID
      for Q_ID in ('+@QuestionList+')
    ) u1
    UNPIVOT
    (
      Comment
      for Comment_ID in ('+@CommentList+')
    ) u2
    WHERE SUBSTRING(Q_ID,2,CHARINDEX(''_'',Q_ID)-2) = SUBSTRING(u2.Comment,CHARINDEX(''Comment'',u2.Comment)+7,3)'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Output

```
ChkID   Q_ID        Comment
1       Q1_ID       Row1 Comment1
1       Q2_ID       Row1 Comment2
1       Q200_ID     Row1 Comment200
1       Q3_ID       Row1 Comment3
2       Q1_ID       Row2 Comment1
2       Q2_ID       Row2 Comment2
2       Q200_ID     Row1 Comment200
2       Q3_ID       Row2 Comment3
3       Q1_ID       Row3 Comment1
3       Q2_ID       Row3 Comment2
3       Q200_ID     Row1 Comment200
3       Q3_ID       Row3 Comment3
4       Q1_ID       Row4 Comment1
4       Q2_ID       Row4 Comment2
4       Q200_ID     Row1 Comment200
4       Q3_ID       Row4 Comment3
```

I've updated that last query to allow for Q_ID to go up into the hundreds, you may need to alter this depending upon your exact data structure.