# SELECT COUNT of multiple column under the same table

Tags: mysql, count

Im blowing my brain on this one. I think I am making this harder than I need to. Im trying to run a mySQL query to SELECT a COUNT of members which have any values in any column. my example table is as such:

[image]

So far, I have got

```
SELECT COUNT(members)
FROM table_1
WHERE '1' IN column_1,
OR column_2,
OR column_3,
OR column_4
```

Please help, I am returning the craziest results

My results should look like

Member----------3

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE 1 IN (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4) ;`

Comment: Thank you for the response. How would I adjust this if the value in the columns is variable. For example instead of '1' next to John smith, what if there were a '2,3,etc.' and I also, i apologize as I didn't update my question properly. I am looking for a result of members----------3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4))
FROM table_1
```

If all columns are `NULL`, `COALESCE()` will also return `NULL` and the row won't be counted.

Answer (score 1):

The use of COALESCE() will do what you ask for very nicely, but I would also question if you might want to reconsider your schema. It looks like what you're doing is tracking individuals' membership in various groups (column_1 ... column_X).

You would probably fare far better to simply make a membership table with two columns: member_id and group_id. You could then more easily add/remove groups from the groups table and counting memberships would have been as simple as a COUNT() on rows matching the member_id in the membership table. This would also set you up better for varying types of members (additional field on membership). Just a thought on a better way to plan for future needs here.

Comment: I would definitely second that - [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186251/34007) is an interesting example of what can happen when the multi-column approach is taken to extremes. The problem is that you start off with 4 columns and then that becomes 5 and then it's difficult to get off the merry go round. Better to make the effort to start with a solid design as you've suggested!